# Limitations Of Not Using Facebook Or Twitter API/SDK In Android App

Tags: android, facebook, api, twitter

I know this is a very simple question and it is also very broad. However I want to implement both Facebook and Twitter into my app. I'm just wondering whether I should definitely bother signing up to both Facebook and Twitter to access their APIs and if I don't, are there limitations to the amount of things I can do in my app without it?

I want to be able to share statuses on Facebook, post photos and the like and also similarly on Twitter.

Any advice would be massively appreciated. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share very limited things to Facebook without using our SDK.  Using the Android intents system, you can only share an URL on Facebook, but cannot pre-fill the message for the user.  It looks something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.mywebsite.com/");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Facebook and Twitter should show up as an option to share the URL if the user has those apps installed.  Besides that, there isn't much else you can do.  With the SDK, however, you can post statuses on the user's behalf, post photos, and much more but requires you sign up to access the APIs.